# admob ads not showing in android apps

Tags: android, admob, ads

Hi in my activitymain java  code i want to show google ads for my android application and i use this code but any ads exist

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But when I add addTestDevice to my code its work but if I delete addtestdevise work and I publish apps, the ads are showing?

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("F9D483C5C3943E9EFDC31D1B4C183CF8")
        .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i want to publish my app i delete this line:
       .addTestDevice("F9D483C5C3943E9EFDC31D1B4C183CF8")

and the ads steel working fine in reel devise